# What is the correct verb to go with "habit"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

What is the correct verb to go with "habit"?

Is it to "do a habit" or to "perform a habit" or something else?

An example of a sentence where I would want to use this verb:
"It's in general much easier to give up a bad habit completely than to try to [missing verb] it in moderation."

Comment: *Indulge*, perhaps?

Comment: See [**Not so fast!**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/37009) _"It's in general much easier to give up a bad habit completely than to try to **persist in** it in moderation."_ "Persist in a habit" is by far the most idiomatic in English.

Comment: We also *form* habits, which is why certain activities and substances are said to be "habit-forming" ...

Comment: @Robusto Yes, but in this context the OP would not say _"...than to try to **forming** it in moderation."_ The idiomatic verb is _persist in._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most general verb to use with habit is *have*, "He has a lot of bad habits."  Because it's so general, however, you can substitute in a variety of other verbs for varied effect.  Consider these quotes:

> The truth is that everyone is bored, and devotes himself to cultivating habits. ― Albert Camus
>
> A man who can't bear to share his habits is a man who needs to quit them. ― Stephen King
>
> Statistics show that of those who contract the habit of eating, very few survive.  ― George Bernard Shaw
>
> I wanted to be a brain surgeon, but I had a bad habit of dropping things.  ― Gilbert Gottfried
>
> One has to grow up with good talk in order to form the habit of it.  ― Helen Hayes

And many more.  In your example, much depends on whether you're going for humor, advice, observation, or something else.  Some possibilities:  *practice, express, indulge, nurse, embrace,* etc.

If you get rid of the "in moderation" then you can simply *moderate* a habit, or *manage, repress, conceal, keep, nurture,* etc.

Comment: We "persist in habits."